# PHP-FPM 7.1 not accepting config parameters in Docker

Tags: docker, php-fpm

I am getting this error on the end of php-fpm container initialization. This one and another with `upload_max_filesize` as unknown entry.

```
[04-Jun-2018 13:07:59] ERROR: [/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf:4] unknown entry 'post_max_size'
[04-Jun-2018 13:07:59] ERROR: Unable to include /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf from /usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf at line 4
[04-Jun-2018 13:07:59] ERROR: failed to load configuration file '/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.conf'
[04-Jun-2018 13:07:59] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

After changing to what was suggested in the comment:

```
[20-Jun-2018 10:31:03] ERROR: [/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf:3] Array are not allowed in the global section
```

My `zz-docker.conf`:

```
[global]
daemonize = no
upload_max_filesize = 4M
post_max_size = 32M

[www]
listen = [::]:9000
user = 1001
group = www-data
```

Comment: Change to `php_value[upload_max_filesize]` and `php_admin_value[post_max_size]`

Comment: Now I am getting this:

`[20-Jun-2018 10:31:03] ERROR: [/usr/local/etc/php-fpm.d/zz-docker.conf:3] Array are not allowed in the global section`

Comment: Move inside the pool configuration `[www]`

Comment: Any specific reason that you are putting those parameters in php-fpm config instead of ini files?

Comment: @Tejas, it helped when I moved it to ini, thanks. I followed some howto or doc when creating this (albeit probably not carefully enough).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained by **Tejas Sarade**, the configuration should reside in the *ini* file, not fpm pool config.